# How to do difference boolean between two objects in Blender?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode

Hello i have 4 cylinders in a "cube" and i want to extrude cube with them.
I want to delete the cylinders and leave holes in cube.

(cylinders in my case are holes for screws).

I tried to use **boolean** but not work or maybe i can't able to use it.

[image]

I hope you can help me...

Here file:
[image]

**edit after use boolean**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the top faces of you cylinders overlay the faces of your cube, which is not good for boolean, you could select all your cylinder, move them up a bit, join them together with a ctrl J, and now boolean the cube

Comment: but if i join them then with what i should to do bollean ? if join i have only one object... i don't understand

Comment: only join the 4 cylinders, not the cylinders with the cube  ;)

Comment: i tried joining only 4 cylinders but when i do bollean not work... maybe is important for you know that i created cylinder with add "circle", then ctrl+f, and extrude it

Comment: that's weird because it works on my computer... Have you moved them up a bit so that the faces don't overlay? Also maybe select all the vertices and recalculate the normals of the cylinders in Edit mode, before the boolean, although I didn't have to do it... And keep in mind that once you've applied the boolean, the original objects that are used to boolean stays in place, you need to move them to see the holes

Comment: yes but not work because the hole should be on the whole thickness :( ... instead there is the hole only on one face .... now I put two photos

Comment: oh ok I see so there might be a topology problem somewhere, wait...

Comment: ok, it's because some vertical faces of your cylinders are sticking to some of the vertical faces of your cube, if you move them a little bit away it will work. It's still a problem of overlaying faces as you can see.

Comment: i must move what ? after boolean ? sorry...

Comment: before boolean, I'm going to answer with pictures, please wait 3mn  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the cylinders you use to boolean your cube have faces overlaying the cube faces, and the boolean doesn't work in these conditions. So here is what you need to do:

- Select your 4 cylinders and join them with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to make it simpler (one boolean instead of 4).
- As you can see the top and bottom faces of the cylinders overlay with the horizontal faces of the cubes. To prevent this, just scale the cylinder object on the Z axis.
- Now there is another overlaying, between some vertical faces of the cylinders and some vertical faces of the cube. So you need to select your cylinders object, go in *Edit* mode, then move each cylinder a bit away from their position on the X axis.
- Now you can apply the *Boolean*, as you can see it works.

[image]

Comment: oh yes now works and now i know use better even boolean..... thanks a lot @moonboots :) :)